# Add dynamic content to an existing HTML5 Web App for Android

Tags: android, html, web-applications, cordova

I have created a mobile web application using HTML5,CSS3 and Javascript/Jquery. I've used the PhoneGap Build to get it's apk.
Once people download the app, If I want to add new content to that app so that the user can see the new content, what is the most **easiest** way to achieve it ?
Is there a way to achieve this without the use of a web service ? 
Whatever is the method you suggest, please go a bit in detail. I'm relatively new to dynamic content, have always been involved with static pages. 
Also, can I use the Admin page template for my HTML5 mobile app too ?

Comment: It depends from where you get your dynamic content. As far as I know, the best way is to use a ajax call to get data from server.

Comment: I'll add them right from my laptop since I have all the required files in it. So yeah, I'll add the dynamic content from my laptop.

Comment: sorry. what do you mean? how you expect your app in your user's devices to get data from your laptop?

Comment: I thought I could do that using an Admin page ? As I said I'm a complete newbie, so sorry if I'm completely wrong. Also, the kind of data I want to load from my laptop to the phonegap app doesn't depend on the request from the user. I'll add it from my laptop and it should get updated in the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are looking for.

As per your comments, you want to push the dynamic content from YOUR laptop to the user's PhoneGap app. This is not possible as there is no way to establish a connection between user's app and your laptop.

You mentioned, you don't want to use server calls. For me that's the only way.

Comment: Alright what kind of server calls are the best for phonegap android apps ?

Comment: Do you have choices? I always do ajax calls using jquerr/javascript.